# Angular2 Http v.s HTTP_PROVIDERS

Tags: angular2-services

I read an article for how to inject Http service into an Angular2 application.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
....
```

I thought Http service already included in the HTTP_PROVIDERS. (as below, according to the document).

```
"The providers included in HTTP_PROVIDERS include:

Http
XHRBackend
BrowserXHR - Private factory to create XMLHttpRequest instances
RequestOptions - Bound to BaseRequestOptions class
ResponseOptions - Bound to BaseResponseOptions class"
```

If that's the case, how come we still need to import Http in? Can we only do

```
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
```

On the other hand, be more specifically, can we change the component providers to 
`providers: [Http]`? 
Or in the bootstrap, can we do `bootstrap(app, [Http])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular2, we can import not only services, but also directives and values (constants) from a module. We import those "TYPES" in order to fulfill the strong-type feature of TypeScript. So we can refer to it in our component class code later.

Comment: Thumbs down  for saying this is related to strong typing.

Answer (score 5):

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` is [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10864).

e.g.: As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10864#issuecomment-244663301), instead of this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],

  providers:    [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
  ],
   ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

use this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],

imports: [
    HttpModule
  ],
   ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note: you import the module in `imports` in `@NgModule`, not the `@Component`.